Socket data streaming works only for a limited amount of file descriptors / data chunks
I am trying to stream several chunks of data (each of them represents an image) using sockets in C++ on a Windows 7 computer and the following code:
int main() {
    std::string _ipaddress = "192.168.0.1"; 
    int dport = 6342;
    
    SOCKADDR_IN dtarget;
    dtarget.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dtarget.sin_port = htons(dport);
    dtarget.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(_ipaddress.c_str());

    SOCKET _data_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (connect(_data_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&dtarget, sizeof(dtarget)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        fd_set read_flags, write_flags;
        FD_ZERO(&read_flags);
        FD_ZERO(&write_flags);
        FD_SET(_data_sock, &read_flags);

        struct timeval waitd;
        waitd.tv_sec = 5;
        int sel;
        sel = select(_data_sock + 1, &read_flags, &write_flags, (fd_set*)0, &waitd);

        if (FD_ISSET(_data_sock, &read_flags)) {
            FD_CLR(_data_sock, &read_flags);

            int readCount = 0;
            int nread = 0;
            int chunkSize = 8576;
            char* chunkBuf = (char*)calloc(chunkSize, 1);
            do {
                if ((nread = recv(_data_sock, chunkBuf + readCount, chunkSize - readCount, 0)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    readCount += nread;
                };
            } while (nread != 0 && readCount < chunkSize && nread != SOCKET_ERROR);
            // do something with chunkBuf
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Basically, the program first connects the SOCKET _data_sock in the code above and enters a for loop afterwards. The fd_sets are declared, set and zeroed inside the loop and subsequently recv() is used to receive the next data chunk in the buffer chunkBuf.
The code works well for the first approximately 30000 chunks (it's not always the exact same number, but close to 30000) and then suddenly starts to fail receiving further data.
I have looked for possible explanations and found that the amount of file descriptors is limited, however, I could not solve the issue e.g. by pulling the declaration outside the loop.
Does anybody have an idea how to adopt the code to be able to receive an unlimited amount of data chunks?

To begin with, if there's an error check what the error is.

Also, are you remembering to check what calloc returns? Are you remembering to free that memory? And why are you even using calloc in a C++ program? Depending on the data you receive, use either a std::string or a std::vector<int8_t>. Pro tip: Whenever you need to use a C-style explicit conversion (a cast) like you do for the result of calloc, then you should take it as a sign that you probably is doing something wrong.

Sorry to chime in on the same tune, but why are you using Windows 7? Further, a [mcve] should compile without changes and still demonstrate the issue. Your code isn't complete, maybe it even contains superfluous parts.

@UlrichEckhardt I still use Windows 7 on my dev machine. Not really relevant to the question at hand.

@Pommesgabel you say "several chunks of data (each of them represents an image)", which doesn't really make sense as that is not how TCP works. Unless your images are all the same fixed size, then you would have to send each image as a separate "message", but you would need to delimit those messages on the TCP stream, such as by sending an image's size before sending its data, but this code is not accounting for that possibility.

@Pommesgabel You say this code is running on Windows, so where is your call to WSAStartup()? socket() will fail without that call, in which case the rest of the code is moot. Also, you are not initializing the waitd.tv_usec field. And you are leaking the chunkBuf. And as mentioned earlier, your error handling needs work.

@Someprogrammerdude and Remy Lebeau: Thanks a lot! The problem was indeed caused by the calloc() & leak of chunkBuf. And I agree, that the error handling should be improved. Plus, I forgot to include the WSAStartup() in the code example (the actual program is more complex and I tried to extract only the relevant parts).

@UlrichEckhardt: The program is supposed to be run on a computer that controls a large research instrument and upgrading to a later Windows version would include reimplementing hundreds of hardware controls and years of reverse engineering.

What happens when it fails?

The while loop escaped, i.e. recv(_data_sock, chunkBuf + readCount, chunkSize - readCount, 0) returned either 0 or a socket error. I did not check which of the two options happens since the problem could be solved by avoiding the leak.
